# How to make the fields independent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make the fields/buttons independent of one another. Just like in the case of `Adding more people`. [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2No3F.png)

No matter how many fields I add, they'll not be linked to each other. I can remove/edit one of them and it'll only affect that field.

but I'm not sure how can I achieve similar behavior If I need to repeat same fields. If I click on `Add Other City`, a new city block would be created but with the previous data.  [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WT7P7.png).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">

  <div v-model="cities" class="city">

    <form action="" v-for="(city, index) in cities">

      <div class="column" v-for="(profile, index) in profiles">
        <input type='text' v-model="profile.name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type='text' v-model="profile.address" placeholder="Address">
        <button type="button" @click="removeProfile">-</button>
      </div>

      <center><button type="button" @click="addProfile">Add More People</button></center>

      <br><br><br>

  </form>
  <center>
    <button type="button" @click="addCity">Add Other City</button>
    <button type="button" @click="removeCity">Remove City</button>
  </center>

  </div>

</div>
```

**JS**:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cities: [
        { name: '' }
    ],

    profiles: [
        { name: '', address: '' }
    ],
  },

  methods: {
    addProfile() {
        this.profiles.push({
        name: '',
        address: ''
      })
    },

    removeProfile(index) {
        this.profiles.splice(index, 1);
    },

    addCity() {
        this.cities.push({
        // WHAT TO DO HERE?
      })
    },

    removeCity(index) {
        this.cities.splice(index, 1);
    },
  }
})
```

Here's a link to Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91m8cf5q/4/

I first tried to do `this.profiles.push({'name': '', 'address': ''})` inside `this.cities.push({})` in `addCity()` but It's not possible (gives error).

What should I do to make them separate so that when I click **Add Other City**, new blank field would appear and removing fields from that city should not remove fields from the previous cities.

Comment: You've only got one array of `profiles`.  And you repeat that for each city.  If you want an array per city, you'll need each city array member to have its own `profiles` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have profiles assigned to individual city

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   cities: [],
  },
  
  mounted(){
   this.cities.push({ 
        name: '',
        profiles: [
            { 
              name: '', 
              address: '' }
      ]
     });
  },
  
  methods: {
   addProfile(index) {
     this.cities[index].profiles.push({
       name: '',
        address: ''
      })
    },
    
    removeProfile(index) {
     this.profiles.splice(index, 1);
    },
    
    addCity() {
     this.cities.push({ 
        name: '',
        profiles: [
            { 
              name: '', 
              address: '' }
      ]
     })
    },
    
    removeCity(index) {
     this.cities.splice(index, 1);
    },
  }
})
```

```css
#app form {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 260px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.column {
  padding: 5px;
}

.city {
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div class="city">

    <form action="" v-for="(city, index) in cities">

      <div class="column" v-for="(profile, index) in city.profiles">
        <input type='text' v-model="profile.name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type='text' v-model="profile.address" placeholder="Address">
        <button type="button" @click="removeProfile">-</button>
      </div>

      <center><button type="button" @click="addProfile(index)">Add More People</button></center>

      <br><br><br>

    </form>
    <center>
      <button type="button" @click="addCity">Add Other City</button>
      <button type="button" @click="removeCity">Remove City</button>
    </center>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Profiles should be part of cities, like this

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cities: [{
        name: '',
      profiles: [
            { name: '', address: '' }
        ]}
    ]
   },

  methods: {
    addProfile(city) {
        city.profiles.push({
        name: '',
        address: ''
      })
    },

   addCity() {
    this.cities.push(
    { name: '',
      profiles: [
            { name: '', address: '' }
        ]}
  )
},

    removeCity(index) {
        this.cities.splice(index, 1);
    },
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">

  <div class="city">

    <form v-for="city in cities">

      <div class="column" v-for="profile in city.profiles">
        <input type='text' v-model="profile.name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type='text' v-model="profile.address" placeholder="Address">
        <button type="button" @click="removeProfile">-</button>
      </div>

      <center>
        <button type="button" @click="addProfile(city)">Add More People</button>
      </center>

      <br><br><br>

  </form>
  <center>
    <button type="button" @click="addCity">Add Other City</button>
    <button type="button" @click="removeCity">Remove City</button>
  </center>

  </div>

  <div>
```